# sqlalchemy: referencing label()'d column in a filter or clauselement

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to perform a query that works across a many->many relation ship between bmarks and tags with a secondary table of bmarks_tags. The query involves several subqueries and I have a need to DISTINCT a column. I later want to join that to another table via the DISTINCT'd ids.

I've tried it a few ways and this seems closest:

```
tagid = alias(Tag.tid.distinct())
test = select([bmarks_tags.c.bmark_id],
              from_obj=[bmarks_tags.join(DBSession.query(tagid.label('tagid'))),
                        bmarks_tags.c.tag_id == tagid])

 return DBSession.execute(qry)
```

But I get an error:

```
⇝ AttributeError: '_UnaryExpression' object has no attribute 'named_with_column'
```

Does anyone know how I can perform the join across the bmarks_tags.tag_id and the result of the Tag.tid.distinct()?

Thanks

Schema:

```
# this is the secondary table that ties bmarks to tags
bmarks_tags = Table('bmark_tags', Base.metadata,
    Column('bmark_id', Integer, ForeignKey('bmarks.bid'), primary_key=True),
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.tid'), primary_key=True)
)

class Tag(Base):
    """Bookmarks can have many many tags"""
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    tid = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True)
```

Comment: Please post your schema so we can reproduce it.

Comment: The SELECT expression looks rather confusing. Do you have the actual SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
t = DBSession.query(Tag.tid.distinct().label('tid')).subquery('t')
test = select([bmarks_tags.c.bmark_id], bmarks_tags.c.tag_id == t.c.tid)
return DBSession.execute(test)
```

Comment: I think this would have worked. I ended up just going about the query very differently. I think I was missing the .subquery() to help me get something that knew what the heck .c.tid was. An alias, etc won't allow that reference. If anyone wants to see the full working implementation/etc you can check it out here: http://goo.gl/GV9x7

Comment: Thanks for this. It was an important hint for my solving a different problem, that of getting a hold of a labeled column later in a whereclause. The solution was to extract the label object and refer to it in both places, e.g., var_col = at.c['X'].label('var_name') ... query = select([at.c['id'], var_col], whereclause=var_col != None)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish, but since you are using orm anyways (and there is not much reason anymore to go with bare selects in sa these days), you  should probably start by establishing a many-to-many relation:

```
bmarks_tags = Table('bmark_tags', Base.metadata,
    Column('bmark_id', Integer, ForeignKey('bmarks.bid'), primary_key=True),
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.tid'), primary_key=True)
)

class Tag(Base):
    """Bookmarks can have many many tags"""
    __tablename__ = "tags"

    tid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True)

class BMark(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bmarks'
    bid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = relation(Tag, secondary=bmarks_tags, backref="bmarks")
```

Then get your query and go from there:

```
query = DBSession.query(BMark).join(BMark.tags)
```

If not, give us the actual sql you are trying to make sqlalchemy emit.